# How to hide a relative layout and all it's child?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to hide a `RelativeLayout` using `setVisibility(View.GONE)`. But it is not working. Please check my code:

```
<LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/AccelerometerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView />
        <TextView />
        <TextView />
        <ImageView />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And I am using the following code for changing the visibility:

```
private RelativeLayout tv;
tv = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.AccelerometerView);
tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Is my approach correct? I know we can hide `TextView`s like this individually. but I want to hide all three `TextView`s and the `ImageView` collectively in a single command. Is there any other way?

Comment: That should work, are you changing visibility somewhere else in the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create methods to alter the visibility of the layout `tv` dynamically.
Set the layout to whatever visibility you require at start up.

I have included checks here, as it was part of some other code and may prove useful if you ever want to include a boolean check on visibility.

Declare your view in the body of your activity, so it can be accessed by any methods.

Activity:

```
RelativeLayout tv;
```

Oncreate:

```
tv = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.AccelerometerView);
```

Use these methods to control the visibility.

Not within create:

```
public void setLayoutInvisible() {
    if (tv.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
public void setLayoutVisible() {
    if (tv.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Use GONE if you don't want the other elements displaced by an INVISIBLE element. You can use this principle for most things.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so as far as default behavior is concerned, setVisibility works on all subviews as well.

Try using

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

in the the xml within the RelativeLayout tag. If the view still shows up then it is being changed in the code somewhere. Post the complete code so maybe we can help.

Answer (score 3):

Your code must work, but try to set layout visibility from xml attributes

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/AccelerometerView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="gone>
```

Comment: I want to change visibility according to an if condition. Changing visibility in XML will limit me. Won't it?

Comment: plese, provide more of your code, will be better if you provide full class